# OpenCV colormap is applied in reverse?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

image = np.loadtxt(sys.argv[1])
print("Matrix rows " + str(image.shape[0]))

image = image
image = image * 255
image = np.uint8(image)

# uint8 Unsigned integer (0 to 255)
heatmap = cv2.applyColorMap(np.uint8(image), cv2.COLORMAP_JET)

plt.imshow(heatmap)
plt.show()
```

I have this simple code but it seems that values the are around 255 are in blue ? where they should be red ?

Comment: If you show the image using opencv cv2.imshow(heatmap) is it correct? If so, then pyplot might be using its own colormap?

Comment: I agree with fmw42. Also, most of the time OpenCV is BGR instead of RGB

Comment: Why don't you just do `plt.imshow(image, cmap='jet')`?

Comment: @QuangHoang oh ok this worked ! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The usual is RGB, in OpenCV, the sequence is BGR.

Answer (score 0):

Before displaying an image, you have to convert it to RGB (or opposite to BGR, if it is already RGB and you want to use it in OpenCV routines) color format like

```py
heatmap_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(heatmap, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
# correction according to @christoph-rackwitz comment
heatmap_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(heatmap, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(heatmap_rgb)
```

then you will see a proper result.

Comment: it's the *opposite*. *matplotlib* wants RGB, OpenCV has BGR order. use `COLOR_BGR2RGB`.